# pip install s3fs with sagemaker-training inside docker causing compatibility issues

Tags: python, docker, pip, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to dockerize my training script on sagemaker. Here what my dockerfile looks like

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver pandas
RUN pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver numpy
RUN pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver sklearn
RUN pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver xgboost
RUN pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver xlrd
RUN pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver fsspec
RUN pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver s3fs
RUN pip3 install --use-feature=2020-resolver sagemaker-training
COPY train.py /opt/ml/code/train.py
WORKDIR /opt/ml/code/
# Defines train.py as script entrypoint
ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train.py
```

When I build my docker image I get following incompatibility error after

Step 9/12 : RUN pip3 install --use-feature=2020-resolver sagemaker-training:

```
Attempting uninstall: botocore
    Found existing installation: botocore 1.17.44
    Uninstalling botocore-1.17.44:
      Successfully uninstalled botocore-1.17.44
ERROR: aiobotocore 1.1.1 requires botocore<1.17.45,>=1.17.44, but you'll have botocore 1.17.54 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed bcrypt-3.2.0 boto3-1.14.54 botocore-1.17.54 cffi-1.14.2 cryptography-3.1 gevent-20.6.2 greenlet-0.4.16 inotify-simple-1.2.1 paramiko-2.7.2 protobuf-3.13.0 psutil-5.7.2 pycparser-2.20 pynacl-1.4.0 retrying-1.3.3 s3transfer-0.3.3 sagemaker-training-3.6.2 werkzeug-1.0.1 zope.event-4.4 zope.interface-5.1.0
```

This is my first attempt on using docker with sagemaker. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sagemaker-training installs the latest `boto3` and I think the `botocore`  version was required by `boto3`. Could you try to install a different version `s3fs`?